Proof that annual nominal interest rate, convertible $m$ times in a year, is a decreasing function
I'm reading the following notes on financial mathematics (they are in italian).
In here the annual nominal interest rate, convertible $m$ times in a year, is defined as (page 32)
$$j(m)=m i_{1/m}$$
it is related to the annual interest rate $i$ by the following relationship:
$$1+i = \left(1+\dfrac{j(m)}{m}\right)^m$$
so that
$$j(m) = m[(1+i)^{1/m}-1]$$
now the notes says  that "it is obvious that $j(m+1)<j(m)$", but it is not so obvious to me (except if I plot the function)
$$
\begin{array}
j(m+1) &= (m+1)[(1+i)^{1/(m+1)}-1] \\
&= m(1+i)^{1/(m+1)}-m+(1+i)^{1/(m+1)}-1 \\
\end{array}
$$
then I'm stuck there

Being lazy,
$$\Delta=j(m)-j(m+1)=m \left((i+1)^{\frac{1}{m}}-1\right)-(m+1)
   \left((i+1)^{\frac{1}{m+1}}-1\right)$$ Using the fact that $i \ll 1$, by Taylor
$$\Delta=\frac{i^2}{2 m (m+1)}\Big(1-\frac{3 m^2+m-1}{3 m
   (m+1)}i+O\left(i^2\right)    \Big)$$
